# open class/window if button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening,

I'm trying to to open a window if a button is pressed.

So for example a button with the id 1 is pressed and then a window pops up. I would do that with a class I guess but I have no idea how I do that...
I would add now a new class in the css file and open it every time the button with the id is pressed but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

```
html:

<button id="1" onclick="info(this.id)">Küche</button>

js:

function info(id) {
    if (id == 1) {

        }
}
```

Comment: You should look into 'click' events - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question...

You must use HTML and CSS to display a "dialog" or "modal" (use terms interchangeably for this answer)

You can take advantage of a front-end framework, like Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/)

or you can use the built in features of your target browsers by using the standard dialog (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

or you can write your own dialog.

You will need to keep track of the selected ID if you want to save the data somewhere and to know which record was clicked for the dialog.

You could also use JavaScript prompt() feature (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) to collect a value from the user.

Another option would be to use a hidden container on the form, populate it with values from the selected item and show/hide it accordingly.

Comment: Obviously I don't know how javascript works, but I think you misunderstood me or I'm just too dumb. If I press button 1 there should pop a new panel on the same site which I can edit in my css file (add buttons, etc.). I don't want to be rude but I think you misunderstood me. I mean let's say I would use "window.open", how would I include this into my other files? I'm sorry for annoying you but I don't get it :D.

Comment: So you are wanting to have a new panel on the site where you can edit and save the CSS for the page? @tableware

Comment: Noo :D. I want just the panel to pop up and I want to edit the panel (adding buttons, etc.) in my one css file but I think I already know how I‘m going to do that. I‘ll add a new class for the panel and add it on a div in html and then I‘ll build a show/hide function for the div in my JavaScript